# "include a php file with html code" for working with ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, file, include, response

Hello friends I have a problem with a php code that I need to work with an AJAX response.

php code not work to php ajax response:

```
if($_GET){
    $data['form']   =       $this   ->  AJAXFORM        ->  GetHTMLAjaxForm();
    $return = json_encode(array('form'=>$data['form']));
    echo $return;
}
```

GetHTMLAjaxForm() //the Function

```
function GetHTMLAjaxForm(){
    $htmlform       =       include('adduser.php'); 
    return $htmlform;
}
```

the file adduser.php have enterely html code that need to be use as a response of ajax callback, plzz check it and say me if i have any mistake becouse when i use it get this error:

```
Ajax, php respond array data error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 4 column 7
```

**Update
with this working part, now lies in a new problem listed below:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516272/html-inserted-with-ajax-not-work-with-other-js-script

Comment: It seems you are trying to parse the response as JSON, which doesn't work if it's HTML.

Comment: but there must be some way to do this?

Comment: the parse json is required because it will be a array.

Comment: So, have you inspected what the Ajax request gets in return? Is that valid JSON (and *only* JSON)?

Comment: which tells me mate up well programmer I can not resibir HTML code as return and pass it through a JSON_Endoce ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to finally get to run this idea was necessary to double GET request by .ajax

```
function GetForms(id){
    $.ajax({
        type:   "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url:        "index.php",
        data:   {idfield:id},
        error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
        success:    function(data) {
            $("#areatitle").html(data.title);
        }
        });
    $.ajax({
        type:   "GET",
        url:        "index.php",
        data:   {idform:id},
        error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
        success:    function(response) {
            $("#formarea").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

and the PHP file:

```
if($_GET){
    if(@$_GET['idfield']){
        $return = json_encode(array('title'=>'titulo nuevo'));
        echo $return;
    }
    if(@$_GET['idform']){
        $data   =       $this   ->  AJAXFORM        ->  GetHTMLAjaxForm();
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

actually what I want is to simplify the amount of request to the server, and to take control of this would be very important.

if someone has a better idea favort communicate in this post.

**with this working part, now lies in a new problem listed below:**

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516272/html-inserted-with-ajax-not-work-with-other-js-script**

Comment: required to work correctly becouse on each .ajax() run a diferent request that need the take the same step..